# Can Delphi ClientDataSets be used in iOS Applications?

Tags: ios, delphi, tclientdataset, client-dataset

I read the ***[Components Not Used in iOS Apps](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Components_Not_Used_in_iOS_Apps)*** post in the Embarcadero DocWiki and was unable to tell if ClientDataSets and DataSources can be used in iOS applications. Can  anyone confim or deny whether these components will work in iOS applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both ClientDataSet and DataSetProvider can be used in iOS applications. The above answer is incorrect, regarding the Data and Datasnap namespaces. These units are cross-platform. You can see this if you pause your cursor over either ClientDataSet or DataSetProvider in the Tool Palette. Doing this displays the OSs supported by the component you are pausing over, and display for both of these components includes both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 3):

The first two items on the list you cite are the *Data.DB* and *Datasnap.DBClient* units, indicating that they are not supported for iOS applications. `TDataSource` comes from the former, while `TClientDataSet` comes from the latter.

To confirm for yourself, try using them in an iOS application and see whether you get the expected compiler error ("Cannot find unit %NameOfTheUnit% used by Project1").

Comment: At the moment ClientDataSets are indeed not supported for iOS applications. Delphi XE2 uses Free Pascal compiler to support iOS. In Delphi XE3 they use own compiler. It is expected that in Delphi XE3 ClientDataSets components can be used in iOS applications. And hopefully also in Android.